# Arrays Ros Launch File

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I get a list of values from a ROS launch file? My launch file includes the following line:

```
<param name="workspace" value="[0.55, 0.9, -0.4, 0.4, -0.25, 2]" />
```

In C++, I try loading that array, but it does not work (the variable *workspace* just always gets set to the constant *WORKSPACE*)

```
std::vector<double> workspace;
node.param("workspace", workspace, std::vector<double>(WORKSPACE, WORKSPACE + sizeof(WORKSPACE) / sizeof(WORKSPACE[0])));
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206146/arrays-ros-launch-file/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2015-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume node is your NodeHandle object? Why use that notation rather than `node.getParam("workspace", workspace)` ?

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2015-03-28**:
This is correct (as far as I know) -- vectors and maps both *require* the `getParam` call. See the [Parameter Server Overview](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists) wiki.

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2015-03-28**:
I have tried `getParam` but it does not get the value from the launch file. Is the syntax in the launch file correct?

**Comment by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) on 2015-03-28**:
Can you query the parameter with `rosparam get /workspace` ? Otherwise another way to set the parameter is `<rosparam param="workspace"> [0.55, 0.9, -0.4, 0.4, -0.25, 2]</rosparam>`. The param tag will default any value that isn't obviously a boolean, int, or double to a string.

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2015-03-28**:
Thanks, using `rosparam` made it work.